# Is it possible to use HttpSession with Tomcat7 in an Ajax Application?

Tags: ajax, session, tomcat7, grails-2.0

I'm developing an Ajax Web Application with `Grails 2.2.3` Backend on a Tomcat 7 Servlet Container. As I ran the application with `grails run` from my IDE everything worked like a charm (i use the `tomcat-grails-plugin` which is providing a Tomcat 7 implementation).

Now if I deploy my Application to a standalone Tomcat 7 I'm not able to work with the `HttpSession` anymore as Tomcat is creating a completely new session on every single Ajax request which makes it impossible for me to work with the session object anymore. As I guess that I'm not the only one who deploys an Ajax Application at a Tomcat 7 I wanted to ask here if anybody could give me some advice on how to solve this problem?

**Is the great invention of preventing Session Fixation by making it impossible to work with Session at all?**

I still want to be able to use `HttpSession` in the way it was meant to be, with this behaviour the idea of a Session gets ad absurdum (in my opinion) if I can't save session related data to it...

Am I seeing something wrong? Am I doing something wrong?

---

### UPDATE

After some research I found out that only a `POST` request triggers the creation of a new session in Tomcat... can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research (even through the source code of the authenticator classes (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/)) I realized that it has to do something with the `Realm` declared in the `server.xml` file which affects all other webapps in the same [engine]/[host] and is there by default to be used with the Tomcat Manager.

As long as I only send `GET` request everything works well, but if I send a `POST` request a new `Session` is created but as I'm not changing the page I'm on (since it's a so called "single page application" I'm always on the same `index.gsp` page) Tomcat treats it as a failed login attempt and keeps on creating new `Session` objects for every `POST` request - and there are a lot of `POST`s on my page ;)

So, as a quick fix I removed the manager from the `webapps` directory and removed the `Realm` declaration from the `server.xml` as I'm already creating a new `Session` on a successful login attempt at my `Grails` backend myself.